# Is this the right group to ask questions about uninterruptible power supplies?

Tags: support

Title has my question:

Is this the right group to ask questions about uninterruptible power supplies?

I found " [https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5279/is-a-question-asking-for-specific-power-consumption-okay"](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5279/is-a-question-asking-for-specific-power-consumption-okay%22), but itdidn't answer my question.

If not, what is the StackExchange group to use to ask UPS questions questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This site isn't for asking questions about consumer devices, this site is more geared toward questions that are about the design of such devices. I'm not sure which site would be best, you can go to any site and then help and on topic

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I already posted a question about PFC Sinewave, but I can deleted it.  I saw a question on UPS on superuser so perhaps someone can help me move it over there.

Comment: @PatS - On our Meta site, asking technical questions (like [your question](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9792) about UPS) is off-topic and not allowed. Therefore I moved it (migrated it) to [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1761497/is-pfc-sinewave-important-when-buying-ups-for-high-end-computer). Then I saw you had the same request here, so yes, your question has been moved.